# Set default values of textbox on external site

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox, youtube

I run a community website and youtube channel, and I am trying to write a script that lets a select number of users access said youtube channel. However I do not want to give my users the password. Is there any way to set the default values of the username and password boxes with javascript or any other language?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JavaScript people can discover what your password is. I don't think there's another way to do this.

**Update**
JavaScript is apparently okay. I would do the following then: create an HTML page on your own server/website, load the YouTube login page in an invisible frame there, fill in the input fields with the necessary information and submit. Then forward them to YouTube.

With jQuery the code to fill in the field would be something like:

```
$('input#email').val('yourlogin');
$('input#password').val('yourpassword');
```

Then submit the form:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Comment: haha I thought about this. The users that I am allowing aren't familiar with HTML, and so if the password is in the HTML of the page, they won't find it, and because of all the javascript in google's pages xD. Do you know how to do this with javascript?

Comment: thanks for the response.. how exactly do i use this code? I am not very familiar with jquery. thanks

Comment: I suspect you lack basic knowledge of HTML and JavaScript. I could be wrong ofcourse and in that case my apologies. If I'm not wrong: I'm not writing a complete script for you and that's not what Stackoverflow is for. Read up on JavaScript a little and then read my answer again.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I do need to catch up on my javascript.

Comment: If you like answers, please upvote them. Good luck with your catching up!